# simple math issue

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to modify an existing *JasperReports* template for an invoice. I would like to do some simple math in one field, i.e. calcultate the tax from an existing gross value. The gross value is represented by a parameter $P{prevAdvanceLine1Sum} and in the next field I would like to simply divide this value by a number (in my case 1.23).
Can you give me the expression I should use and what expression class to set?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use simple arithmetic operators (like " / " in this case. See example here: [EL Basic Arithmetic](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/ExpressionLanguageBasicArithmetic.shtml)), or use the pre-defined methods provided by iReports. Which means, right-click upon the *TextField* and select **Edit Expression**. Then select the **divide()** method.

 So the two methods would be:
1. $P{prevAdvanceLine1Sum / 1.23}
2. $P{prevAdvanceLine1Sum}.divide( 1.23 )

Comment: First option resulted in error:  Parameter not found : prevAdvanceLine1Sum / 1.23    The second option resulted in error:  The method divide(double) is undefined for the type String
value = ((java.lang.String)parameter_prevAdvanceLine1Sum.getValue()).divide( 1.23 ); //$JR_EXPR_ID=61$

Comment: Does the $P{prevAdvanceLine1Sum} represent a String value?

Comment: In that case, it should be obvious that you should either change it's data type to int/double/number or convert this string to an int/bigdecimal. You can't invoke arithmetic operations (like division) for a string, it doesn't make any sense.